# Given the function $f$, evaluate $f'$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

> Let $$f(x) = \ln \left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right).$$ Evaluate $f'$.

The answer key is $f' = \frac{-1}{x\ln10}$. I have no idea how to start because of $|x|$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Start with positive $x$. Then $f(x) = \ln(1/x)$. Your derivative is definitely wrong.

Comment: Did you mean that $f(x) = \lg (1/|x|) = \log_{10}(1/|x|)$? Because $\ln(x) := \log_{\mathrm e}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  You can break it into cases: $f(x)=\begin{cases} \ln(\frac1x), x\gt0\\\ln(-\frac1x), x\lt0\end{cases}$.

Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Let $g(x)=|x|$, then $g'(x)=\mathop{\rm sgn} x$ for $x\neq 0$; but then you will need to use some properties for $|x|$ and $\mathop{\rm sgn} x$ at the very end, such as $|x|=x \cdot \mathop{\rm sgn} x$ and $\dfrac{\mathop{\rm sgn} x}{x}= \dfrac{1}{x \cdot \mathop{\rm sgn} x}$.